# Replace $1, $2, $3... in a String with an array of values

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a `String command` and a `String[] args` array of arguments passed to the command. Assuming the list is of the correct length, how would I replace all instances of `$1`, `$11`, `${12}` with the corresponding argument from the list?

For instance, if the command is `"move $1 to $2 while using the ISO-${3}34 standard"`, and `args = {"X", "Y", "SC"}`, the command should be changed to `"move X to Y while using the ISO-SC34 standard"`.

What I'm doing currently is:

```
for (int i = args.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    String bracketedArg = "${" + i + "}";
    if (commandString.contains(bracketedArg)) {
        commandString = commandString.replace(bracketedArg, args[i]);
        continue;
    }
    else {
        String arg = "$" + i;
        commandString = commandString.replace(arg, args[i]);
    }
}
```

Is there a more robust way of accomplishing this? I tried to do it using a regex expression but I wasn't sure how to actually replace the matches:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\{?\\$(\\d+)}");
commandString = pattern.matcher(commandString).replaceAll(???)
```

Comment: Is that initial string you have really fixed or do you have control over how those placeholders are named? I ask because what you describe is _exactly_ what string format functions like `printf()` already offer in a very robust and comfortable manner ...

Comment: I have some control over it but I'm quite restricted. I'm parsing commands from minecraft's console so I'm constrained by the rules of the game's parser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a `Function` callback to `Matcher#replaceAll`.

```java
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{?(\\d+)}?");
String res = pattern.matcher(str).replaceAll(mr->args[Integer.parseInt(mr.group(1))-1]);
System.out.println(res);
```

Comment: Note that you can avoid the implicit `substring` operation of `group(int)` by using [`parseInt` with offsets](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.CharSequence,int,int,int)): `replaceAll(mr -> args[Integer.parseInt(str, mr.start(1), mr.end(1), 10)-1])`. It’s a bit more complicated but more efficient in most cases.

Comment: Lovely, this is exactly what I was looking for.